# VCCodeModel not in VCCodeModel namespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, namespaces

I am working with VCCodeModel in both C# and C++ CLR and I am having trouble getting the VCCodeModel type in to the CLR project.  I have added Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCCodemodel as a reference, but when I type:

```
Microsoft::VisualStudio::VCCodeModel::VCCodeModel
```

Visual Studio cannot see the code model.  All the other objects in the namespace like VCCodeFunction and VCFileCodeModel all work, but this one fails.

[VCCodeModel Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vccodemodel.aspx)

Is there some error that could cause this? I am using the default add-in project with C++ CLR as the chosen language and have added Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCCodeModel as a reference, and can successfully reference the other members in the space.  What could the issue be here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a bug/quirk with the IDE's Intellisense for C++.  Even if you fully-qualify a class name, if the class name is the same as the namespace name, it will not show up in intellisense.  Nor will the IDE recognize it as a class-- the color of the class name stays black, not light blue like other classes.

Luckily, this is a purely cosmetic IDE problem. The class will still work fine in your code, will still compile, etc. You just have to type the name of the class yourself. :-)

Furthermore, the problem only extends to the class name, not the class's members. If you create a managed reference to VCCodeModel in your code, you'll be able to see intellisense for its members.

Here's a repro illustrating the intellisense issue in a plain unmanaged class :

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public: 
            static int x();
    };
    public class Foo
    {
        public: 
            static int x();
    };
    public class Test
    {
        void ThisIsATest()
        {
            ::Foo::        // intellisense will show Bar and Test, but not Foo
            ::Foo::Foo::   // you will see "x" in intellisense
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Feel embarassed that this is what the problem was, but thanks, it was simply not showing up in intellisense.